# asp.net Session being shared between two separate instances of Firefox (12)

Tags: asp.net, session

I am setting a session variable once user login (Session["loginuser"]) and redirecting to another page using Response.Redirect. I am testing this in two seperate instance of Firefox browser. Used two different login's. Login works fine, but after login if I click any link on browser window 1 and click the any other link on browser window 2, window 2 is showing username of window 1 !!!

Don't know what is the problem.. can somebody help!

Comment: possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026128/ie-7-ie-8-etc-multiple-tab-browser-session-problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sessions are kept on a per browser basis using cookies. This means that when you are using the same browser on the same computer they are going to be shared. This may or may not be a problem, as it will not affect users unless being able to log in to multiple accounts on the same computer is necessary.

This artcile will tell you about how to turn on cookie-less sessions which will solve your problem: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx

Essential what you should do is go to your web.config and find the line that looks like below and change cookieless to true.

```
<configuration>
  <sessionstate 
  mode="inproc"
  cookieless="true" 
  timeout="20" 
  sqlconnectionstring="data source=127.0.0.1;user id=<user id>;password=<password>"
  server="127.0.0.1" 
  port="42424" 
 />
```

Comment: If I say cookieless="true" or cookieless="UseUri", it keeps redirecting me back to login page.

Comment: You may need to modify the redirect that you are doing. It is important that the session data that is now embedded in the URL is maintained. Are you using an absolute URL? Try switching the contents of your response.redirect to a relative URL if it isn't already.