# Session variables are not specific to one user

Tags: asp.net, session

i have two ASP.net systems, both of them use the same DB and are on the same server, I keep the user id in session variables, unfortunately, i noticed that in the finance system, some payments are made by a sales person on which it was supposed to be done by cashier. How is that possible? Does ASP.Net scatter the session variables between different users?

Taking into consideration, that, the finance system, users are forced to login from specific IP address attached to each cashier.

Answer (score 2):

Session state is unique per user of the web application. From this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87069683%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> ASP.NET session state identifies requests received from the same
>   browser during a limited period of time as a session, and provides the
>   ability to persist variable values for the duration of that session.

I can assure you that ASP.net does not 'scatter' the session variables between different users.

If the users are sharing the same computer, then the issue may be with using cookie based sessions. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026128/ie-7-ie-8-etc-multiple-tab-browser-session-problem) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802712/asp-net-session-being-shared-between-two-separate-instances-of-firefox-12) question discuss solving this problem.